# Undo INF changes

Tags: wix, inf

I have an INF file for a filter driver in my WIX installer.

I want to know. Is there any way to UNDO the changes made by this INF file during unsinstallation?

Comment: The uninstall task of the Driver installation framework should uninstall the inf file. Has the Inf file things to uninstall, like uninstall sections?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what changes you need to make, then you could write a custom action that executes on uninstall: [How to add a WiX custom action that happens only on uninstall (via MSI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320921/how-to-add-a-wix-custom-action-that-happens-only-on-uninstall-via-msi). How you go about modifying the .ini file is up to the implementation of your custom action.