# "Installed" condition is always true when installing or uninstalling in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) installer which does some work, and at the end, launch RSYNC installer (it's an EXE file, no problem to have both working at same time).

But when uninstalling, I want to remove RSYNC too.

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallRSyncDaemon" FileKey="cwRsyncServer_4.0.5_Installer.exe" ExeCommand="/q" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no" />
<CustomAction Id="UninstallRSyncDaemon" FileKey="rsync_uninstall.bat" ExeCommand="[INSTALLDIR]" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
<CustomAction Id="EditConf" FileKey="rsync.bat" ExeCommand="[INSTALLDIR]" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='InstallRSyncDaemon' Before='InstallFinalize'>(NOT remove="ALL")</Custom>
  <Custom Action='EditConf' After='InstallRSyncDaemon'>(NOT remove="ALL")</Custom>
  <Custom Action='UninstallRSyncDaemon' Before='RemoveFiles'>remove="ALL"</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

My problem is that during uninstalling, the Custom Action 'UninstallRSyncDaemon' is skipped:

```
MSI (s) (58:78) [17:37:40:475]: Skipping action: UninstallRSyncDaemon (condition is false)
```

I have tried with "installed" and other conditions, with the same result.

At the beginnning of the log file, I have:

```
MSI (c) (9C:80) [17:37:36:772]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (9C:80) [17:37:36:772]: Doing action: INSTALL
Action 17:37:36: INSTALL.
Action start 17:37:36: INSTALL.
MSI (c) (9C:80) [17:37:36:772]: UI Sequence table 'InstallUISequence' is present and populated.
MSI (c) (9C:80) [17:37:36:772]: Running UISequence
MSI (c) (9C:80) [17:37:36:772]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EXECUTEACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
```

If I try to change to the condition to launch it during installation, it is working, so for me it is just the statement of the condition.

But I do not understand why, this is the condition always used in a tutorial or in an answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What if the user has installed RSync themselves? What if another installer for a program that depends on RSync takes the same approach? Seems a very short-sighted "my program is the only one that matters" approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think the remove should be in upper case. Try this.

```
REMOVE="ALL"
```

But it will run in modify and Upgrade also. Check more about this condition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/731700/1124244).