# How can I perform a custom action in WiX that only executes on install or uninstall?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, custom-action, merge-module

I have two custom actions, one of which I'd like to execute when my product is installed and the other when it is uninstalled.

My custom action is currently called from a merge module after the "InstallFinalize", but this happens for both install and uninstall. I've tried adding the "NOT INSTALLED AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE" condition, but that gave me an error:

> Error 2762. Cannot write script record. Transaction not started.

I've also tried attaching to other actions (for example, UnpublishComponents), but I can't find any that are unique to install or uninstall.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a WiX custom action that happens only on uninstall (via MSI)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320921/how-to-add-a-wix-custom-action-that-happens-only-on-uninstall-via-msi)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try next
`1.` Only for Installation:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="SomeAction" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

`2.` For Uninstall try to use: [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321874/884220)

[UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property is set only during `RemoveExistingProducts` CA.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The variable “`INSTALLED`” should be using is “`Installed`”. Find more information regarding the Install and uninstall conditions in the Stack Overflow answer *[How to add a WiX custom action that happens only on uninstall (via MSI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/731700/1124244)*.