# Is it possible to run a custom action only in repair mode

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2012

I need to run a custom action only during Repair. But I didn't find a valid condition to do so. 
If I specify a custom action with below condition, it runs in Modify mode as well as in Repair mode.

`Installed AND Not REMOVE`

I am using InstallShield 2012 spring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [REINSTALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property. Conditional statement on your custom action should look like REINSTALL<>""

Answer (score 1):

REINSTALL="" will be evaluated to True during the install and uninstall phases so the exact condition is **(Installed and NOT REMOVE) AND (REINSTALL="")** 
because (Installed and NOT REMOVE) is True during Modify and repair operations but during repair REINSTALL property will be set to blank

Answer (score 1):

**For future reference** check these cheat sheets:

- [Installshield condition cheat sheet](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/IS-CHS-Common-MSI-Conditions.pdf).
- [How to add a WiX custom action that happens only on uninstall (via MSI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320921/how-to-add-a-wix-custom-action-that-happens-only-on-uninstall-via-msi/17608049#17608049)

I have not had the time to go through all these conditions and test them, but the latter table looks reasonable at face value. However:

I believe `REMOVE` can sometimes be set during installation for example (and change) - it is very complicated to deal with all permutations of possibilities since MSI's command line interface and property configuration is so flexible.

The **Installshield cheat sheet** I have never actively used or checked. Please check their suggestions for repair - there are different ones depending on how the repair is invoked.

Please remember to also **check self-repair** - just delete the main application EXE and trigger self-repair by then invoking the application's advertised shortcut (if any). It has been years since I checked, but self-repair may only run actions between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize.