# what will be the condition for custom action to run only on first installation in InstallShield?

Tags: vbscript, installation, windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2010

I have a requirement to delete the files if the customer has installed the `exe` for the first time and uninstalled it.

If the user has upgraded the `exe` without uninstalling the present installer and trying to uninstall the upgraded installer we should leave the files as it is.

I have tried the conditions for the custom action as below, but it is not working. The files are getting deleted in both the cases.

```
NOT(is_major_upgrade or is_minor_upgrade)
REMOVE ~="ALL"
Not Installed
```

Can you please help with this?

Thanks in advance,

Panvith

Comment: can  you define 'the files'? Do you have user created files that should be deleted on uninstall? Or are you asking for instructions on handling major upgrades and file replacement / overwrite /uninstall and reinstall scenarios?

Comment: That really wasn't clear to me I am afraid, but you can find [**some links to MSI installer conditions here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533711/is-it-possible-to-run-a-custom-action-only-in-repair-mode/48117013#48117013).

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys..... i found a way to do this..