# MSI uninstallation sequence after an MSP was installed

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I had an MSI with a CA type 1. Later on, I realized that CA had to be changed so I updated it and created an MSP.

**Q1**: If I install the MSI and then apply the MSP, I don't think the cached MSI (one in Windows\Install directory) contain the updated CA, right?

**Q2**: If I uninstall this MSI, does the installer uninstall the MSP first and then the MSI?

**Q3**: Which CA would be performed during uninstallation? An updated CA or the original CA? Or an updated CA first and then the original CA?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a minor or major upgrade MSP? In other words, did you change the product code, the package code and the product version - leaving the upgrade code the same?

Comment: Hi @Stein, The MSP in question is a minor update. Due to my ignorance, I still don't understand if there is "major upgrade MSP" as I never heard of it. I thought all MSP's are minor update (not major nor upgrade).

Comment: I did make a major upgrade MSP many years ago, but it never worked properly. Not sure if anything is different now. It sounds like your minor upgrade MSP should work OK. Remember to test install, patching, and uninstall scenarios. Ideally an upgrade scenario after patching as well.

Comment: @Stein. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: No problem, please be sure to read some updates in my answer and the advice to check if your uninstall is working outside of a major upgrade (in which case you can just use an uninstall command and not a patch to fix the problem - see end of my answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (typically) the \windows\installer directory there is the cached MSI and any patches that have been installed for that product. When some installation action is performed the cached MSI and all its related patches are "merged" to create the view of the actual currently installed patched product, so:

So Q1 doesn't really apply because nothing is done with the cached MSI on its own. If you look at it with Orca it won't reflect the patch, because that's in a separate MSP file.

Q2: There is no first and last because the (MSI+Patches) is what is uninstalled, followed by clean up removing the files that are no longer needed.

Q3: There is only one CA in (MSI+Patches) and that's what is called.

Answer (score 1):

PhilDW has attended to your specific questions, maybe I can make a few guesses as to what the underlying problem really is.

Is this a minor or major upgrade MSP? A minor upgrade patch can be used to "hotfix" errors in the installed MSI's uninstall sequence - if that is what you are really asking. I have done so many times, and when you install the patch first and then uninstall, what is running on uninstall is what you included in your MSP - the new CA - provided you installed everything correctly (command line, etc...). The MSP is merged to the cached MSI - as Phil states - at runtime. What I am a little fuzzy on, is how any applied transforms are handled - this is something I have never had the time to test. Are you using transforms?

This approach is frequently used when you discover an error in the installed setup's uninstall sequence which prevents a major upgrade from running correctly. In a regular major upgrade the old custom action may or may not run from the old setup depending on [**how it is conditioned**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533711/is-it-possible-to-run-a-custom-action-only-in-repair-mode/48117013#48117013) (see link for some conditioning cheat sheets), but typically it either runs undesirably, returns an unexpected error that triggers an undesirable rollback or the whole custom action crashes, causing a failed major upgrade (or failed uninstall).

The above yields [**a catch 22 situation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)) where your existing install appears un-uninstallable and un-upgradeable - but a minor upgrade can come to the rescue (a regular MSI installed as a minor upgrade should also work - it shouldn't need to be delivered as a patch, provided that you properly re-cache the new MSI from the command line - a patch is merely a distribution mechanism for an upgrade that is already working).

---

A **major upgrade patch (MSP)**, on the other hand, will not allow you to fix errors in the uninstall sequence of the existing installation since it triggers the uninstall sequence of the pre-existing install and just tells it: "uninstall yourself" - as part of the major upgrade operation. When this happens, then the old CA is used - which is embedded in the cached MSI for the old setup. It is the old setup running - unchanged.

It has been over a decade since I made a major upgrade patch - I find them pretty bad and I avoid them if possible. There are too many problems - and honestly: a few serious logical flaws (for example the fact that the product you are trying to patch may already have been uninstalled - if you schedule RemoveExistingProducts early - see below - a rather ridiculous error, one would have to say). I have never made a major upgrade patch using WiX, but I tried with Installshield and briefly with Wise. In order for them to run at all, you have to set the uninstall of the old version to happen after the install of the new version (so the old version isn't already gone by the time you try to patch). This means RemoveExistingProducts must be late in the InstallExecuteSequence - which makes the setups vulnerable to component referencing errors (another common problem).

**UPDATE**: I should also add that my major upgrade test - done many, many years ago - also had problems with feature state migration (**MigrateFeatureStates**) - the patch caused all features to show up in an unknown state. To this date I have never had the time to figure out exactly what happened, but I think it may have been my own doing. I did something funky with the [**Preselected property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370839(v=vs.85).aspx) (I think it may have been related to a merge module doing something stupid - and I tried to "fix" it - with another fix that didn't fix anything, but caused new problems - and such forth and whatnot :-) - deployment is fun). Just reporting the failure, and whatever intel I have - not claiming to have any solutions. There were also other problems - but most of them were Installshield specific I think. WiX might do a lot better. Wise was sensationally good for minor upgrades (they really did work), but I never used Wise for a real major upgrade.

A typical major upgrade custom action problem is that the custom action is erroneously conditioned and will run in both the old version's uninstall, and the new version's install. There are many modes to test your conditions in, and you will be surprised if you take the time to do so: **install**, **repair**, **modify**, **uninstall**, **patch**, etc... And you will often find that the custom action runs unexpectedly on modify or repair operations or similar. I linked to a couple of cheat sheets for conditions above, here it is again: [Is it possible to run a custom action only in repair mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533711/is-it-possible-to-run-a-custom-action-only-in-repair-mode/48117013#48117013).

**UPDATE**: And a common patch problem is that custom actions may run unexpectedly because they are not conditioned with `NOT PATCH`. Rant: I wish patching would be its own thing in MSI and not just a delivery mechanism for a regular update, and that it would target files only and have its own installation sequence (like admin install has). This would allow "targeted patching" and small hotfixes for huge products - which really need some working, down-to-earth patching that is not overambitious and over-complicated (which is what patching in MSI currently is - in all honesty).

---

Advice? Use a minor upgrade patch or a regular minor upgrade (not delivered as a patch) to fix the uninstall problem, and then proceed to use your normal upgrade approach. It should be possible to deliver all this in a WiX Burn bundle - but I have never had time to test it.

My 2 cents? Forget patching if your product is small, and just use a regular minor upgrade MSI. If your product is huge, then use a patch package (or your download bundle will be a lot larger than necessary). Be aware that your future setup bundles should also contain the "hotfix" patch / MSI to allow users with older installations to fix the uninstall error before installing the latest version. A little clunky, but it should be manageable. If your old setup has a working uninstall, but fails as a major upgrade (because of an insignificant error in the uninstall sequence making the whole process fall over), you can uninstall the old setup with a regular uninstall command passed to `msiexec.exe` and then install the new version afterwards (avoiding the major upgrade scenario by performing a manual uninstall first). I haven't tested this with Burn yet.