# Wix - Do Not Remove Pinned Taskbar on Install

Tags: windows-7, wix, installation, taskbar

During an installation or major upgrade, if a user has pinned the application to their task bar, then after the installation has completed, the task bar shortcut is removed from `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` and a blank-file icon (see image link below) is left in its place.

Clicking the icon will prompt the user to delete as it doesn't target anything.

[image]
(Mirror: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz1zW.png)

I would like to make it such that the taskbar shortcut is not removed at all when installing or running a major upgrade. We push out updates on a weekly basis and it can be frustrating if the taskbar shortcut breaks during every update.

Is this possible?
I've read about modifying the value for `RemoveExistingProducts` (i.e. changing from `InstallValidate` to `InstallFinalize`), but I'm unsure if this will be viable.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I've got the same issue and can't seem to find the solution anywhere...

Comment: @Uflex See my answer for workaround we use in our product.

Comment: @Andreas See my answer for workaround we use in our product.

Comment: @Uflex Thanks. This seems more elegant than the approach I chose: we use a component with emtpy guid.  We remove the shortcut file with a custom action on uninstall.

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid custom actions by disabling the standard RemoveShortcuts as follows:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RemoveShortcuts>Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</RemoveShortcuts>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This disables removing shortcuts except on uninstall.

Comment: Tested this on Windows 10, works like a charm! This should be the accepted answer. The only issue is that the taskbar shortcut won't remove itself when uninstalling but this is something I can live with.

Comment: @Crono have you found a way to remove it on uninstall?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17608049/5369075) if you want to tweak the condition. I think this will still remove the shortcut on a repair.

Answer (score 5):

We encountered this issue and our investigation reveals that msiexec.exe explicitly removes pinned item when remove corresponding shortcut on uninstall or major upgrade.

As workaround we did the following:

1. Disabled standard `RemoveShortcuts` action using the following WiX code:

   ```xml
   <InstallExecuteSequence>
     <RemoveShortcuts>0</RemoveShortcuts>
   </InstallExecuteSequence>
   ```
2. Added explicit `<DeleteFile>` entry for every shortcut we install. For example:

   ```xml
   <DirectoryRef Id="ProgramMenuDir">
     <Component Id="Component" Guid="B7469BFC-BF2A-4AF7-9DF5-3458BB485F18">
       <Shortcut Id="Shortcut" Name="My Supper App"
                 Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Target='MyApp.exe' />
       <RemoveFile Id="RemoveShortcut"
                   Name="My Supper App.lnk"
                   On="uninstall" />
     </Component>
   </DirectoryRef>
   ```

It seems to be working fine.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what you can do to prevent it from happening, but this might help you at least replace it. This method uses a logon script, but you should be able to implement this with wix

> Windows 7 taskbar pinned icons are stored in the following locations
>
> File System:  %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User
>   Pinned\TaskBar
>
> Registry:
>   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband]
>   To deploy it, you can perform the following steps:
>
> 1. Configure Pinned items on a Windows 7 system as a reference computer.
> 2. Export Reigstry Key to pinned.reg file:   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband]
>      And copy items in the "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick
>      Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar" to a shared folder.
> 3. Create a logon script to deploy the registry keys and copy the corresponding files.   Please note that the
>      “%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned”
>      folder is only created after a user has pinned an icon to the taskbar.
>      In the logon script, you will need to create the
>      “%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User
>      Pinned\TaskBar” folder if it does not exist.

Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d172b4de-be7c-4149-8958-bebfe042ade1/forum-faq-how-to-deploy-windows-7-taskbar-pinned-icons-by-group-policy?forum=winserverGP