# Uninstallation condition for WIX

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, custom-action, wix3.7

For installation, we have a property "**Install**" which we can use in conditions to execute if its undergoing installation. Do we have a similar property for **Uninstallation**?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

---

You can use `REMOVE~="ALL"` to detect a **full uninstallation**.

---

An uninstall performed as part of a major upgrade can be detected via the [**UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE property**](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/understanding-upgradingproductcode-property).

---

**Here is some further advice and some help resources**: here is a **"[MSI Conditions Cheat Sheet](http://www.flexerasoftware.jp/webdocuments/PDF/IS-CHS-Common-MSI-Conditions.pdf)"** to help you get the complicated MSI conditions for custom actions right. The sheet looks fine to me, but I have not tested it in detail - just sharing the link with your own testing as the only guarantee.

Also, you can check out **Stefan Kruger's** **[msifaq.com](http://www.msifaq.com)** for a list of common MSI questions as well as his main [**installsite.org**](http://www.installsite.org/) site for general deployment information.

With regards to Wix check out [**this well known wix tutorial**](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial). I'll throw in a link to the [Windows Installer Best Practices list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204770(v=vs.85).aspx) as well.

[How to add a WiX custom action that happens only on uninstall (via MSI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320921/how-to-add-a-wix-custom-action-that-happens-only-on-uninstall-via-msi?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the great explaination. Had tried REMOVE~=ALL, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Here's my condition which I am evaluating - 
Installed Or VCREDIST_INSTALLED Or REMOVE~="ALL"
 where VCREDIST_INSTALLED is evaluation if the VC++ redistr are already installed

Comment: You must use ALL in quotes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368013(v=vs.85).aspx and keep in mind that if your product has features that can be added and removed it may be more useful to have a condition related to a feature being added or removed.

Comment: Thanks @PhilDW, I already had the quotes, but it doesn't work as intended yet. What do you mean by having a condition related to the feature? I need this check to block the installation/uninstallation from proceeding if VC++ is not installed

Comment: How is the VCREDIST_INSTALLED property set? Remove that property temporarily and check if the remaining condition works as expected.

Comment: The REMOVE syntax with ALL quoted is the correct condition, Glytzhkof is probable correct in suggesting that the vc redist property is the problem.