# How to delete service while uninstallation of the msi in wix?

Tags: service, wix, uninstallation

I have created one installer using wix toolset and wanted to delete service at the time of uninstallation of the msi, but service name will be create dynamically like if user will ente companyname at the time of installation then service name will be Servicename_companyname.

In my case service is getting stopped but not deleted at the time of uninstallation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WiX Remove files on uninstall but not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450864/wix-remove-files-on-uninstall-but-not-update)

Comment: Without seeing your `WXS` code and your uninstall log, it's really hard to tell what went wrong and how to help you get it right.