# Is there an updated truth table for WiX custom action conditions?

Tags: wix

I am trying to get some custom actions working properly on my install.

[This is the table I am using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17608049/1364759) for my logic in Wix (provided by ahmd0)

The problem is that it just doesn't seem to be working. Here are my conditions currently:

```
<Custom Action='RemoveService' After='InstallInitialize'>Installed</Custom>

<Custom Action='WaitForFileLocks' After='InstallInitialize'>Installed</Custom>

<Custom Action='InstallService' Before='InstallFinalize'>NOT REMOVE ~= "ALL" OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>

<Custom Action='MergeConfigFiles' Before='InstallFinalize'>NOT REMOVE ~= "ALL" OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>
```

The behavior I expect from this:

- RemoveService and WaitForFileLocks should be run on uninstalls and upgrades.
- InstallService and MergeConfigFiles should be run on installs and upgrades.

The behavior I am seeing:

- RemoveService and WaitForFileLocks are running on uninstall, but NOT upgrades.
- InstallService and MergeConfigFiles is being run on install, but NOT upgrades.

Is the table I am using wrong? Is my logic correct? Could my issue be Windows' recognition of what an "upgrade" is? I checked in Add/Remove programs after I increased all 3 version numbers for my install and the new version is properly updating there.