# how to add a WIX custom action that happens before uninstall?

Tags: c#, wix

This is my first time using WiX, and I'm still getting the hang of custom actions. What would be a basic example of a custom action that will run a batch script before uninstall?

for example ,prompt user or do anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a WiX custom action that happens only on uninstall (via MSI)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320921/how-to-add-a-wix-custom-action-that-happens-only-on-uninstall-via-msi)

Comment: Also consider Rob's perspective at the end his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/321874/2226988).