# How can I trigger a component condition only on uninstall, but not on an upgrade?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.9

I want to remove the file `File.txt` only on uninstall, but not on an upgrade. We are using the `<MajorUpgrade ...>` element for upgrades.

When we use the following Component, the File will be removed every time, also on an upgrade:

```
<Component Id="RemoveFileComponent" Transitive="yes"  Directory="BIN" Guid="MY-GUID-HERE">
  <Condition>REMOVE=ALL AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Condition>
  <RemoveFile Id="RemoveTextFile" Name="File.txt" Directory="BIN" On="uninstall" />
</Component>
```

The attribute `<RemoveFile ... On="uninstall" />` changes nothing on this behaviour. The file will be consequently deleted when doing an upgrade.

**UPDATE:**
In an `<CustomAction>REMOVE=ALL AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</CustomAction>` the condition works correctly on an update or uninstall, but the same condition does not work correctly in and component condition: `<Condition>REMOVE=ALL AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Condition>`. I am not interested to use an `<CustomAction>` in combination of an assembly or command line statement as and unstable workaround. I am not requesting for a solution using a `<CustomAction>` described here: [How to add a WiX custom action that happens only on uninstall (via MSI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320921/how-to-add-a-wix-custom-action-that-happens-only-on-uninstall-via-msi)
I want to get work it with a component condition, described in my question.

Comment: Please look @ my question. I want to use no custom action. I want to use a component. This is no duplicate.

Comment: Note that you can @ ping gold badge closers, like @Yan in this instance

Comment: I don't think there's an actual difference. The main point in your question is how to set the proper condition. Besides, `<RemoveFile>` is also a custom action under the hood.

Comment: No. Look @ my Update.

Answer (score -1):

Make a custom action and specify the condition of the following :[image]

Comment: Look @ my question: I do not want to use an CustomAction. I want to use an `<RemoveFile />`