# Suppress custom action during upgrade for already released MSI

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade

I have an already released MSI that has a custom action scheduled to run when UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE is true. The action I released looks like this:

```
<Custom Action="DoThing" After="InstallFinalize" >
  NOT REMOVE OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE
</Custom>
```

The problem is I DON'T want it to run when my users upgrade. The action SHOULD have looked like this

```
<Custom Action="DoThing" After="InstallFinalize" >
  NOT Installed
</Custom>
```

but unfortunately I didn't think this process through before I sent it out the door. So my question is what can I do? Is there any way to suppress this action in my next version's actions?

Comment: This table has helped me a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/a/731700/600559

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what patches are for. You are using WiX, so you could create a bundle that first installs the patch with the corrected condition then does the upgrade with the new MSI.