# Uninstall MSI that was not installed with bootstrapper. Only uninstall when bootstrapper is uninstalling

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I have an msi that is not installed by my bootstrapper that needs to be uninstalled when the bootstrapper is being uninstalled(not when it is being installed). Is there a way to do this in burn?

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom action and set its `ExeCommand` attribute to the `msiexec` uninstall command with the `/x` parameter. You will need to know the product code of that MSI.

```
msiexec /x {Package | ProductCode}
```

You can read more about msiexec command and its parameters over [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_Uninstall).

EDIT: To prevent it from running during installation set the condition of the custom action to `Remove="ALL"`. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/320921/6570665).

Comment: This was my thought as well. My only concern was how to prevent the execution during initial installation of the bootstrapper.

Comment: Check edit. Let me know if that doesn't work or if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

Not today, there's an open feature request for bundles to be able to uninstall arbitrary MSI's by ProductCode - https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4858.