# How to execute a custom action when a user changes a feature from 'selected' to 'unselected'?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, wix3

I want to execute my Custom Action if **user is unselecting a specific feature**. It doesn't matter if this is during a `Repair`, `Upgrade` or `Uninstall`.
The action should **not** be executed, when during a Upgrade the feature is reinstalled.

With my research:
[Action-Conditions](https://www.firegiant.com/docs/wix/v3/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/expression-syntax/), [Conditional Statement Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/conditional-statement-syntax?redirectedfrom=MSDN), [Property-Table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17608049),
[_UPGRADE Property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51215272), [execute an action only on Uninstall, neither on repair, nor upgrade nor install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74023116/1196586)

I come to this solution:

_UNINSTALLONLY Property, that help to execute the Custom Action only on uninstall:

```
<SetProperty Id="_UNINSTALLONLY" After="FindRelatedProducts" Value="1">
       <![CDATA[Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE]]></SetProperty>
```

And my deferred CustomAction inside my `InstallExecuteSequence`:

```
<Custom Action="HandleMyFeatureMyCustomActionOnUnselect" Before="InstallFinalize">
  <![CDATA[_UNINSTALLONLY AND (!MyFeature >= 2) AND (&MyFeature <= 2) ]]></Custom>
```

This works, **expect when User is unselecting feature on upgrade**. Then the action is **not** called.

I tried:

`(!MyFeature >= 2) AND (&MyFeature <= 2)`:  Problem: Action is called on upgrade, **even User doesn't change selection**

`_UNINSTALLONLY AND (&MyFeature <= 2)`: Problem: Action is also called, when I unselect **another Feature2** on Upgrade

Now I feel a little bit lost.

Another requirement is that, during a product upgrade, the old version is reliably removed. Additionally, it is important to preselect the features based on their current status in the setup. I have successfully achieved this.
To rule out any interactions with my issue, here is some additional context:

```
<CustomAction Id="HandleMyFeatureMyCustomActionOnUnselect" BinaryKey="FeatureCustomActions"
    DllEntry="HandleMyFeatureMyCustomActionOnUnselect" Impersonate="no"  Execute="deferred"  
    Return="check" />

<CustomAction Id="SetHandleMyFeatureMyCustomActionOnUnselectPropertyValues" Property="HandleMyFeatureMyCustomActionOnUnselect" 
    Value="INSTALLFOLDER=[INSTALLFOLDER]" />    
    
<Property Id='INSTALLFEATURE'>
        <RegistrySearch Id='InstallFEATURE' Root='HKLM'
                        Key='SOFTWARE\Somewhere\AnotherKey'
                        Name='FEATUREINSTALLED' Type='raw' />
</Property>
```

The `InstallExecuteSequence`

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="SetREINSTALL" Before="CostInitialize">
            Installed AND REMOVE ~= "" AND NOT REINSTALL
   </Custom>
   <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize"/>
   ...
   <Custom Action="SetHandleMyFeatureMyCustomActionOnUnselectPropertyValues" Before="HandleMyFeatureMyCustomActionOnUnselect" ><![CDATA[_UNINSTALLONLY AND (!MyFeature >= 2) AND (&MyFeature <= 2) ]]></Custom>
   <Custom Action="HandleMyFeatureMyCustomActionOnUnselect" Before="InstallFinalize"><![CDATA[_UNINSTALLONLY AND (!MyFeature >= 2) AND (&MyFeature <= 2) ]]></Custom>
   ...
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The `Features`

```
<Feature Id="MyFeature" Title="My Feature" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"  Display="expand" Level="1">
    <Condition Level="2">INSTALLFEATURE=0</Condition> 
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="FEATURE"/>
</Feature>
<Feature Id="MyFeature2" Title="My Feature2" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"  Display="expand" Level="1">
    <Condition Level="2">INSTALLFEATURE2=0</Condition> 
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="FEATURE2"/>
</Feature>
```

So my question is:
How to execute a custom action when a user changes a feature from 'selected' to 'unselected'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, with

```
<SetProperty Id="_NEWINSTALLER" After="FindRelatedProducts" Value="1">
   <![CDATA[NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE]]></SetProperty>
```

and the condition

```
<Custom Action="SetHandleMyFeatureMyCustomActionOnUnselectPropertyValues" Before="HandleMyFeatureMyCustomActionOnUnselect" >
    <![CDATA[_NEWINSTALLER AND (!MyFeature >= 2) AND (&MyFeature <= 2) ]]></Custom>
<Custom Action="HandleMyFeatureMyCustomActionOnUnselect" Before="InstallFinalize">
    <![CDATA[_NEWINSTALLER AND (!MyFeature >= 2) AND (&MyFeature <= 2) ]]>
</Custom>
```

I was so damn close! Now it's going through the test :-)

Comment: tests passed so accepting as answer