# Remove file and folders on uninstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, wix3

I am learning WIX to build installer for my app but I am stuck with removing files. My question is how can I remove files and folders on uninstall. When I click on remove button, all the files and folders which the installer created doesn't remove on uninstall.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195919/removing-files-when-uninstalling-wix addresses this, but it looks like that's wix2 and i'm guessing you're using wix3.0 or 3.5?

Comment: thanks for your reply James, yes you are right i am using wix 3.0, let me see the solution link which you gave

Comment: no, actually i had visited this link and find nothing which works for me. and one more thing to ask related to my problem is i am not getting the point of following line whenever i search for removefile element; it is in help file, <RemoveFile> = "Remove a file(s) if the parent component is selected for installation or removal" how we can select parent component to uninstall?

Comment: This is a duplicate as suggested by James Polley. Wix 2.0 or 3.0 doesn't matter, the linked answer is valid for both.

Comment: thank you wcoenen, after your reply i put my effort on practicing james poley posted link, and it is working now, and why it is not working before because i let guid value empty.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is in the comments above but for future reference there are two things to check first when files are not being removed:

1. Ensure that you do not have Component/@Guid="". In Specifically setting to an empty string (Guid="") tells the Windows Installer *ignore* all the stuff built into this Component. Note: WiX v3.6+ you can leave the Guid attribute of the Component element completely and that is fine (a stable GUID will be generated).
2. Ensure the you do not have Component/@Permanent="yes". Obviously, that tells the Windows Installer to not uninstall the stuff.

Comment: My application directory under Program Files wasn't being removed. I had to add GUIDs even though it installed fine without them. Thanks!