# Uninstalling msi does not remove application files

Tags: windows-installer

When i uninstall my application,it does not remove the application folder neither the files in the application folder (exe and dlls).

I had a problem when i install a newer version of my windows application,it doesn't override the dlls and keep using the old dlls as long as they have the same assembly version.

I solved this issue by upgrading the dlls assembly versions, but still i want to remove old files on upgrading.

Comment: How are you building your installer (Wix/VS/InstallShield/NSIS/Wise)?

Comment: I am using the visual studio setup project.

Comment: Feels like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013475/why-doesnt-my-new-windows-installer-file-msi-install-properly-over-an-older-v?rq=1) might help or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012531/remove-file-and-folders-on-uninstall?rq=1)

Comment: A verbose log file for the unistall is necessary to root cause the reason the files are being left behind. You can generate one by doing `msiexec /l*v log.txt /x path\to\your.msi`. From there we could help you.