# How can I remove .NET isolated storage setting folders during WiX uninstallation?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, wix3

I would like to remove the isolated storage folders that are created by a .NET application when using My.Settings etc.  The setting files are stored in a location like

```
C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Roaming\App\App.exe_Url_r0q1rvlnrqsgjkcosowa0vckbjarici4
```

As per this question [StackOverflow: Removing files when uninstalling Wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195919/removing-files-when-uninstalling-wix) I can uninstall a folder using:

```
<Directory Id="AppDataFolder" Name="AppDataFolder"> 
    <Directory Id="MyAppFolder" Name="My"> 
        <Component Id="MyAppFolder" Guid="YOURGUID-7A34-4085-A8B0-8B7051905B24"> 
            <CreateFolder />
            <RemoveFile Id="PurgeAppFolder" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" /> 
        </Component> 
    </Directory> 
</Directory>

<!-- LocalAppDataFolder-->
```

This doesn't support sub-folders etc.  Is the only option a custom .NET action or is there a more simple approach for removing these .NET generated setting folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is experiencing the same issue, I used a custom .NET action to remove the folders.  The WiX documentation provided a good example on how to create the action.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, if you don't know the folders at build time to fill in the RemoveFile table entirely, then you have to create a custom action.

You might also find the [WixContrib project](http://wixcontrib.codeplex.com/) useful. It contains RemoveFolderEx extension to address this very problem. As it states, the code is of medium production quality. Never tried it myself, though...