# How can I setup a .NET Custom Action within WiX 3.0?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I need to setup a custom action within WiX 3.0.  I have the following setup in my Windows application exe.

I have viewed the question at [StackOverflow: Removing files when uninstalling Wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195919/removing-files-when-uninstalling-wix)  however I can't get this working with WiX 3.0.  This seems to deal with InstallUtilLib.dll, however I can't work out how I call the custom action within my main Windows app executable.

Also, is there some method that I can use to manually invoke and test the OnBeforeUninstall function is working as expected?

```
Imports System.Configuration.Install.Installer
Imports System.IO

Public Class CustomInstaller
    Inherits Configuration.Install.Installer

    Protected Overrides Sub OnBeforeUninstall(ByVal savedState As System.Collections.IDictionary)
        MyBase.OnBeforeUninstall(savedState)

        Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InstallUtil is an ugly antipattern.  If you need a managed CustomAction you should use WiX's DTF pattern.    Also you should attempt to avoid CustomActions all together whenever native WiX/MSI functionality will handle your needs.   Have you tried to use the RemoveFile element?

Comment: RemoveFile won't remove subdirectories and files etc.  I am dealing with isolated storage and removing the settings where I don't know the file names.  How about if my app can remove settings with the command line "App.exe /reset"?  How would I run that in the Programs Files before it is removed?

Comment: It is true, RemoveFile won't remove directories recursive.  So here's how I roll....

I write an immeadiate custom action using C#/DTF that emits temporary records into the RemoveFiles table during the install.   This way all I have to do is the business logic of what I need deleted.    Window Installer then handles the actual execution of that deletion including rolling back the deletes if the uninstall is aborted.

Comment: Thanks, sounds fine.  I have located an example of the DTF and WiX at http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson3.php#3.5  However I notice that sfxca.dll is either x86 or x64.  I only do one build of my application as the .NET framework will run it in 64bit if appropriate.  Do I need to handle this manually in the custom action?

Comment: You probably want to choose x86 then.  MSI isn't Any CPU, you have to say one or the other but by saying x86 you'll run in WOW64 on x64 as a 32bit process.   Once installed your EXE can continue to be Any CPU.