# WiX - Optionally remove user-generated files on uninstall

Tags: deployment, wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.5

I want to give the users an option to leave their data when the app uninstalls, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195919/removing-files-when-uninstalling-wix

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen This is not a duplicate at all; this specifically asks how to prompt the user with the option.  The other question only asks how to do it automatically, without user interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both yes and no.

No UI is shown during uninstall, that's why you cannot give users this option.

Yet you can remove these files as described in [the answers to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195919/removing-files-when-uninstalling-wix) linked by Morten.
Additionally you can use [`RemoveFolderEx`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_removefolderex.htm) element from Util extension. This element correctly handles removal of subdirectory structure.

---

As for UI part, some programs do not display several buttons, like *Uninstall*, *Change*, *Repair*, on the Control Panel rather have one button *Uninstall/Change*. In the latter case, there's usually UI shown when they are uninstalled.

Comment: I do get some UI when I uninstall, are you saying it's not possible to add a checkbox?

Comment: No, I didn't say that. I said that the UI is usually minimal during uninstall, therefore users can't select the check box.