# WIX Installer, on Uninstall, removing files from Temp Directory

Tags: file, directory, wix, installation

I am using the following simplified installer to test the removal of files from the temp directory.  My application will create some files in the directory and I want them to be deleted when the application is uninstalled.

Looks like it should be working, the logging doesn't seem to show much useful information.  Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?  I have included the WixUIExtension and WixUtilExtension; in this case I hand create the testTest.txt file and it never gets deleted.  I'm obviously missing something.

## **Updated Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

    <Product Name=        "tempApp"
             Manufacturer="tempCompany"
             Id=          "*"
             Language=    "1033"
             Version=     "1.0.0.0"
             UpgradeCode= "{BC29783A-3F6B-4A10-A9BF-3C3F63AF7F68}">

    <Package Id=                "*"
             Keywords=          "tempApp,Installer"
             Description=       "-- TBD --"
             Comments=          "tempApp (c) 2019, tempCompany"
             Manufacturer=      "tempCompany"
             Languages=         "1033"
             InstallerVersion=  "200"
             Compressed=        "yes"
             InstallScope=      "perMachine"
             Platform=          "x64"/>

    <!-- Force an upgrade of the older versions to the newer version -->
    <Upgrade Id="{BC29783A-3F6B-4A10-A9BF-3C3F63AF7F68}">
      <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect=     "no"
                      Property=       "PREVIOUSFOUND"
                      Minimum=        "1.0.0.0"
                      IncludeMinimum= "yes"
                      Maximum=        "99.0.0.0"
                      IncludeMaximum= "no"/>
    </Upgrade>

    <!-- Warn if there is a newer verison of the applicaiton already installed -->
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />

    <!-- Disable the Restart Manager Control, doesn't work very well, will have to do it manually afterwards. -->
    <Property Id="MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL" Value="Disable" />

    <!-- Defines the name and information on the CAB file that is embedded inside the MSI, doesn't ever need to be changed -->
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="testApp.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <!-- Setup the UI to be minimal, and then display the EULA -->
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal"/>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="EULA.rtf"/>

    <!-- Sets up the location where the Custom Actions will be executed -->
    <Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#applicationFolder]"/>

    <!-- Define the directory where the files are supposed to go -->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">

      <!-- Create the tempApp Folder in the Program Files Directory -->
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder" Name="ProgramFilesx64">

        <!-- Define the Directory where the files of the application are to be placed -->
        <Directory Id="applicationFolder" Name="testApp">
          <!-- Test Application File -->
          <Component Id="testApp_Component" Win64="yes">
            <File Id=       "testApp"
                  Name=     "testApp.exe"
                  Source=   "testApp.exe"
                  KeyPath=  "yes"/>
            <RemoveFile Id=   "AppTesting"
                        On=   "uninstall"
                        Name= "Testing.txt"/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="testBatch_Component" Win64="yes">
            <File Id=       "testBatchApp"
                  Name=     "testBatch.bat"
                  Source=   "testBatch.bat"
                  KeyPath=  "yes"/>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <!-- Define the Temporary Directory -->
      <Directory Id="tempData" Name="TempFolder">
        <Component Id="tempBatchFile" Guid="{FD8CFE50-436A-4BAA-B9DD-F2E091481AB3}" Win64="yes">
          <File Id=     "testBatch"
                Name=   "testBatch.bat"
                Source= "testBatch.bat"
                KeyPath="yes"/>
          <RemoveFile Id=   "testTest"
                      On=   "uninstall"
                      Name= "Testing.txt"/>
        </Component>
      </Directory>

    </Directory>

    <!-- Define what is considered a complete install -->
    <Feature Id=    "CompleteInstall"
              Title= "tempTest"
              Level= "1">
      <ComponentRef Id="testApp_Component"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="testBatch_Component"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="tempBatchFile"/>
    </Feature>

  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Other Links I have been reading, they seem to all apply to files in the same directory as the application is installed in.
**Other Links I've been trying to follow**

- [Orphaned on
  Removal](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/getting-started/orphaned-on-removal/)
- [WiX installer not removing files on
  uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848971/wix-installer-not-removing-files-on-uninstall?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment74062688_19865783)
- [Wix RemoveFile and RemoveFolder for removing leftovers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470189/wix-removefile-and-removefolder-for-removing-leftovers?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How can I delete generated folders and files via Wix on uninstall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766359/how-can-i-delete-generated-folders-and-files-via-wix-on-uninstall?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Removing files when uninstalling WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195919/removing-files-when-uninstalling-wix)

## **INSTALL LOG FILE**

```
=== Logging started: 7/3/2019  9:22:14 ===
Action 9:22:14: INSTALL. 
Action start 9:22:14: INSTALL.
Action 9:22:14: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 9:22:14: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 9:22:14: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:14: PrepareDlg. 
Action start 9:22:14: PrepareDlg.
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Normal textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Bigger textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 19 pixels height.
Action 9:22:14: PrepareDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 9:22:14: PrepareDlg. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:14: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 9:22:14: AppSearch.
Action ended 9:22:14: AppSearch. Return value 0.
Action 9:22:14: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 9:22:14: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 9:22:14: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:14: ValidateProductID. 
Action start 9:22:14: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 9:22:14: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:14: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
Action start 9:22:14: CostInitialize.
Action ended 9:22:14: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:14: FileCost. Computing space requirements
Action start 9:22:14: FileCost.
Action ended 9:22:14: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:14: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
Action start 9:22:14: CostFinalize.
Action ended 9:22:14: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:14: MigrateFeatureStates. Migrating feature states from related applications
Action start 9:22:14: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 9:22:14: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
Action 9:22:14: WelcomeEulaDlg. 
Action start 9:22:14: WelcomeEulaDlg.
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Title textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 14 pixels height.
Action 9:22:14: WelcomeEulaDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 9:22:17: WelcomeEulaDlg. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:17: ProgressDlg. 
Action start 9:22:17: ProgressDlg.
Action 9:22:17: ProgressDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 9:22:17: ProgressDlg. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:17: ExecuteAction. 
Action start 9:22:17: ExecuteAction.
Action 9:22:18: INSTALL. 
Action start 9:22:18: INSTALL.
Action 9:22:18: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 9:22:18: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 9:22:18: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 0.
Action 9:22:18: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 9:22:18: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 9:22:18: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: ValidateProductID. 
Action start 9:22:18: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 9:22:18: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
Action start 9:22:18: CostInitialize.
Action ended 9:22:18: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: FileCost. Computing space requirements
Action start 9:22:18: FileCost.
Action ended 9:22:18: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
Action start 9:22:18: CostFinalize.
Action ended 9:22:18: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: MigrateFeatureStates. Migrating feature states from related applications
Action start 9:22:18: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 9:22:18: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
Action 9:22:18: InstallValidate. Validating install
Action start 9:22:18: InstallValidate.
Action ended 9:22:18: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: RemoveExistingProducts. Removing applications
Action start 9:22:18: RemoveExistingProducts.
Action ended 9:22:18: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: InstallInitialize. 
Action start 9:22:18: InstallInitialize.
Action ended 9:22:18: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
Action start 9:22:18: ProcessComponents.
Action 9:22:18: GenerateScript. Generating script operations for action:
GenerateScript: Updating component registration
Action ended 9:22:18: ProcessComponents. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: UnpublishFeatures. Unpublishing Product Features
Action start 9:22:18: UnpublishFeatures.
Action ended 9:22:18: UnpublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: RemoveFiles. Removing files
Action start 9:22:18: RemoveFiles.
Action ended 9:22:18: RemoveFiles. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: InstallFiles. Copying new files
Action start 9:22:18: InstallFiles.
InstallFiles: File: Copying new files,  Directory: ,  Size: 
Action ended 9:22:18: InstallFiles. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: RegisterUser. Registering user
Action start 9:22:18: RegisterUser.
Action ended 9:22:18: RegisterUser. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: RegisterProduct. Registering product
Action start 9:22:18: RegisterProduct.
RegisterProduct: Registering product
Action ended 9:22:18: RegisterProduct. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: PublishFeatures. Publishing Product Features
Action start 9:22:18: PublishFeatures.
PublishFeatures: Feature: Publishing Product Features
Action ended 9:22:18: PublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: PublishProduct. Publishing product information
Action start 9:22:18: PublishProduct.
PublishProduct: 
Action ended 9:22:18: PublishProduct. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: InstallFinalize. 
Action start 9:22:18: InstallFinalize.
Action 9:22:18: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
1: {8AC268E8-DB18-4769-A515-73B9BF048CCF} 2: {33F795F0-CF34-5459-8836-0FFC648586A1} 3: C:\Program Files\testApp\testApp.exe 
1: {8AC268E8-DB18-4769-A515-73B9BF048CCF} 2: {C91144C7-3133-5BDB-8ACD-192C7CC1DA58} 3: C:\Program Files\testApp\testBatch.bat 
1: {8AC268E8-DB18-4769-A515-73B9BF048CCF} 2: {FD8CFE50-436A-4BAA-B9DD-F2E091481AB3} 3: C:\TempFolder\testBatch.bat 
Action 9:22:18: InstallFiles. Copying new files
InstallFiles: File: testApp.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\testApp\,  Size: 9
InstallFiles: File: testBatch.bat,  Directory: C:\TempFolder\,  Size: 52
InstallFiles: File: testBatch.bat,  Directory: C:\Program Files\testApp\,  Size: 52
Action 9:22:18: RegisterProduct. Registering product
RegisterProduct: {8AC268E8-DB18-4769-A515-73B9BF048CCF}
Action 9:22:18: PublishFeatures. Publishing Product Features
PublishFeatures: Feature: CompleteInstall
Action 9:22:18: PublishProduct. Publishing product information
1: {8AC268E8-DB18-4769-A515-73B9BF048CCF} 
Action 9:22:18: RollbackCleanup. Removing backup files
Action ended 9:22:18: InstallFinalize. Return value 1.
Action ended 9:22:18: INSTALL. Return value 1.
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {BC29783A-3F6B-4A10-A9BF-3C3F63AF7F68}
Property(S): applicationFolder = C:\Program Files\testApp\
Property(S): tempData = C:\TempFolder\
Property(S): WixUIRMOption = UseRM
Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(S): ARPNOMODIFY = 1
Property(S): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(S): TARGETDIR = C:\
Property(S): SourceDir = Z:\SOFTWARE-DISTRIBUTION\Testing\
Property(S): MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL = Disable
Property(S): WixShellExecTarget = [#applicationFolder]
Property(S): Manufacturer = tempCompany
Property(S): ProductCode = {8AC268E8-DB18-4769-A515-73B9BF048CCF}
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): ProductName = tempApp
Property(S): ProductVersion = 1.0.0.0
Property(S): DefaultUIFont = WixUI_Font_Normal
Property(S): WixUI_Mode = Minimal
Property(S): ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = PREVIOUSFOUND;WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
Property(S): MsiLogFileLocation = Z:\SOFTWARE-DISTRIBUTION\Testing\installer.log
Property(S): PackageCode = {4A3B3BD3-D454-4BA4-B42A-1170B3BC5F46}
Property(S): ProductState = -1
Property(S): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = Z:\SOFTWARE-DISTRIBUTION\Testing
Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 9088
Property(S): USERNAME = Windows User
Property(S): COMPANYNAME = Test Company Inc.
Property(S): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): ROOTDRIVE = C:\
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(S): SECONDSEQUENCE = 1
Property(S): ADDLOCAL = CompleteInstall
Property(S): MsiSystemRebootPending = 1
Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(S): VersionNT = 603
Property(S): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(S): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(S): WindowsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\
Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(S): System64Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\
Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(S): TempFolder = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(S): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\
Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\<user>\Favorites\
Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\<user>\Documents\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\
Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\<user>\Pictures\
Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\
Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(S): Msix64 = 6
Property(S): Intel = 6
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 16383
Property(S): VirtualMemory = 14552
Property(S): LogonUser = <user>
Property(S): UserSID = S-1-5-21-1039747452-301181775-3212777973-4608
Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ComputerName = SCI-555VM
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768
Property(S): CaptionHeight = 23
Property(S): BorderTop = 1
Property(S): BorderSide = 1
Property(S): TextHeight = 16
Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(S): ColorBits = 32
Property(S): TTCSupport = 1
Property(S): Time = 9:22:18
Property(S): Date = 7/3/2019
Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.7.3056.0
Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.17134.1
Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(S): AdminUser = 1
Property(S): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\WINDOWS\Installer\53a5126.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = Z:\SOFTWARE-DISTRIBUTION\Testing\testInstaller.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 5
Property(S): Preselected = 1
Property(S): CostingComplete = 1
Property(S): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(S): SOURCEDIR = Z:\SOFTWARE-DISTRIBUTION\Testing\
Property(S): SourcedirProduct = {8AC268E8-DB18-4769-A515-73B9BF048CCF}
Property(S): ProductToBeRegistered = 1
Action ended 9:22:18: ExecuteAction. Return value 1.
Action 9:22:18: ExitDialog. 
Action start 9:22:18: ExitDialog.
Action 9:22:18: ExitDialog. Dialog created
Action ended 9:22:19: ExitDialog. Return value 1.
Action ended 9:22:19: INSTALL. Return value 1.
Property(C): UpgradeCode = {BC29783A-3F6B-4A10-A9BF-3C3F63AF7F68}
Property(C): LicenseAccepted = 1
Property(C): applicationFolder = C:\Program Files\testApp\
Property(C): tempData = C:\TempFolder\
Property(C): WixUIRMOption = UseRM
Property(C): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(C): ARPNOMODIFY = 1
Property(C): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(C): TARGETDIR = C:\
Property(C): SourceDir = Z:\SOFTWARE-DISTRIBUTION\Testing\
Property(C): MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL = Disable
Property(C): WixShellExecTarget = [#applicationFolder]
Property(C): Manufacturer = tempCompany
Property(C): ProductCode = {8AC268E8-DB18-4769-A515-73B9BF048CCF}
Property(C): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(C): ProductName = tempApp
Property(C): ProductVersion = 1.0.0.0
Property(C): DefaultUIFont = WixUI_Font_Normal
Property(C): WixUI_Mode = Minimal
Property(C): ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg
Property(C): SecureCustomProperties = PREVIOUSFOUND;WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
Property(C): MsiLogFileLocation = Z:\SOFTWARE-DISTRIBUTION\Testing\installer.log
Property(C): PackageCode = {4A3B3BD3-D454-4BA4-B42A-1170B3BC5F46}
Property(C): ProductState = -1
Property(C): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(C): CURRENTDIRECTORY = Z:\SOFTWARE-DISTRIBUTION\Testing
Property(C): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(C): CLIENTPROCESSID = 9088
Property(C): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(C): MsiSystemRebootPending = 1
Property(C): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(C): VersionNT = 603
Property(C): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(C): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(C): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(C): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(C): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(C): WindowsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\
Property(C): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(C): System64Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
Property(C): SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\
Property(C): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(C): TempFolder = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(C): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(C): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(C): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(C): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\
Property(C): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\<user>\Favorites\
Property(C): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(C): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\<user>\Documents\
Property(C): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(C): RecentFolder = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(C): SendToFolder = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(C): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(C): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(C): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\
Property(C): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\<user>\Pictures\
Property(C): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(C): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(C): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(C): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(C): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(C): FontsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\
Property(C): GPTSupport = 1
Property(C): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(C): Msix64 = 6
Property(C): Intel = 6
Property(C): PhysicalMemory = 16383
Property(C): VirtualMemory = 14556
Property(C): LogonUser = <user>
Property(C): UserSID = <something>
Property(C): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(C): ComputerName = SCI-555VM
Property(C): SystemLanguageID = 1033
Property(C): ScreenX = 1920
Property(C): ScreenY = 1200
Property(C): CaptionHeight = 23
Property(C): BorderTop = 1
Property(C): BorderSide = 1
Property(C): TextHeight = 16
Property(C): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(C): ColorBits = 32
Property(C): TTCSupport = 1
Property(C): Time = 9:22:19
Property(C): Date = 7/3/2019
Property(C): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.7.3056.0
Property(C): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.17134.1
Property(C): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(C): AdminUser = 1
Property(C): Privileged = 1
Property(C): USERNAME = Windows User
Property(C): COMPANYNAME = Test Company Inc.
Property(C): DATABASE = C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\53a9b49.msi
Property(C): OriginalDatabase = Z:\SOFTWARE-DISTRIBUTION\Testing\testInstaller.msi
Property(C): SOURCEDIR = Z:\SOFTWARE-DISTRIBUTION\Testing\
Property(C): VersionHandler = 5.00
Property(C): UILevel = 5
Property(C): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): ROOTDRIVE = C:\
Property(C): CostingComplete = 1
Property(C): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(C): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
=== Logging stopped: 7/3/2019  9:22:19 ===
MSI (c) (80:28) [09:22:19:715]: Product: tempApp -- Installation completed successfully.

MSI (c) (80:28) [09:22:19:715]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: tempApp. Product Version: 1.0.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: tempCompany. Installation success or error status: 0.
```

## **Latest Findings**

By looking at the install log, it appears that TempFolder is NOT assigned the right value until later in the install, thus the files are being copied to c:\TempFolder instead of c:\Users\\AppData\Temp which appears to be valid further down in the log file.  I have tried setting the "Value" to "TempFolder", "[TempFolder]", and "[#TempFolder]" but all just result in a c:[TempFolder Name].

Comment: Shouldn't your application do this cleanup on its own?

Comment: Ideally it would, but some of this information is shared across sessions and needs to be created / remain.  I could easily code a custom action to remove these files during uninstall, but I shouldn't have to do this, WiX is more than capable of doing it for me.  Just trying to figure out why it doesn't remove the files.

Please note that the files I'm mostly concerned with are in other, but similar directories than Temp.  The code I've linked here is just to show the problem I'm having, I'm quite confident if I fix this it will fix the others.

Comment: I have been trying to follow this link : [Removing files when Uninstalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195919/removing-files-when-uninstalling-wix) but it seems to only apply to files in the same directory as the application is installed in.  This is why I'm asking about the Temp directory file removal, it should be similar but it isn't working.

Comment: Just and update, I ended up writing a stand alone custom action to delete the files that I want to have removed when the application is uninstalled.  I could never figure out how to get wix to do this.  :(

Answer (score 0):

No real answer, but my solution was to write a custom action to perform the clean up that I was trying to get the WiX tool to perform.  Not an ideal solution, but it work.  If anyone has a better method of doing this, where I don't need to write my own cleanup code, that would be appreciated.