# WIX MSI: Uninstall of package is not deleting the installation directory root path

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, wix3.5

During the installation process selected the directory as C:/Test/ (root path for the installation location) for installing my application. It installed successfully in this location (C:/Test/). Uninstalled this package, it is removed all installed files and subdirectories. But not removed the installed root directory (i.e. C:/Test). below custom action is using to delete/remove the installation root path and installation files (with subdirectories).

```
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />
        <Custom Action="ApplicationInstallDir" After="AppSearch">APPINSTALLDIR</Custom>
        <Custom Action="DeleteInstallDir" Before="RemoveFiles" >
            REMOVE="ALL"
        </Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
<CustomAction Id="DeleteInstallDir" BinaryKey="CommandPrompt"
        ExeCommand="cmd /C pushd &quot;[APPINSTALLDIR]&quot; &amp;&amp; (rd /s /q &quot;[APPINSTALLDIR]&quot; 2>nul &amp; popd)"            Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no" />
```

Comment: Windows Installer should be uninstalling this automatically without the need to call a cmd session.  There's other problems with your installer.

Comment: ..and in addition to Chris's comment, you wouldn't use code either because WiX offers a RemoveFile element.

Answer (score 1):

Use verbose logging of the uninstallation to find the root of the problem:

```
msiexec /x SetupProject.msi /L*V log.txt
```

If you install to a non-default directory, verify that `[APPINSTALLDIR]` is set correctly on uninstallation. (For me, it was not.)

**Note that there might be a better way:**

WiX supports recursive removal of files and folders with [RemoveFolderEx](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/removefolderex.html). An explanation how to use it can be found at [hass.de](https://www.hass.de/content/wix-how-use-removefolderex-your-xml-scripts). This removes left over files and deletes all directories including the root installation path.
I switched from a custom DLL action to `RemoveFolderEx` and it worked fine.

Your problem might also be covered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195919/removing-files-when-uninstalling-wix)

Comment: hi - can anyone comment if this solution worked?  I am having a similar problem and am looking for different solutions...

Comment: It is not worked for me. still the problem is there. And in Windows-Xp m/c it is not removing log files (which are created during the application using). But these log files are deleting during uninstall in case of Windos-7 and Windows-8