# How can I delete generated folders and files via Wix on uninstall?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wix, .net-4.5, wix3.9

After an installation, I have the following folder structure in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)`:

[image: Folder Structure after install]

The Path to the folder `generated` is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\CompanyName\AppName\generated`

The folder `generated` contains subfolders and files they will be created by the application during the runtime via C# code:

```
var lPathToDir = Path.Combine(lFileService.GetFilePath, pSamAccountName);

if (!Directory.Exists(lPathToDir))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(lPathToDir);
}
```

The variable `lPathToDir` could have the values:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CompanyName\AppName\generated\user1
// or
C:\Program Files (x86)\CompanyName\AppName\generated\user2
```

Then it looks like:

[image]

**My Problem:** After an uninstall, these subfolders `user1`, `user2` will not be removed. I use the following Wix declaration:

```
<!-- Target installation folder -->
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="$(var.ProgramFilesFolder)">
    <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="$(var.AppFolderName)">

      <Directory Id="BIN" Name="bin" />
      <Directory Id="HELP" Name="help" />
      <Directory Id="GENERATED" Name="generated" />

      <Component Id="RemoveAll" Guid="THE-GUID-HERE">
        <RemoveFile Id="RemoveAllFilesOnUninstall" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveAllFoldersOnUninstall" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" On="uninstall" />
        <util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="GENERATED" />
      </Component>

    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

After uninstall:

[image]

Why do these folders stay and how can I remove these generated folders from the installation folder? Perhaps do I need to set any permissions when I create these folders via C#?

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195919/removing-files-when-uninstalling-wix) should help you. Specifically, the top 2 top-rated answers.

Comment: @Yan Sklyarenko: As you can see, I already use the solution of the best ranked answer with no success.

Comment: Ah, right, missed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works now with `RemoveFolderEx` as suggested by Bob Arnson. But in addition to the declaration `<util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />` there are also some registry declarations necessary:

```
<!-- add this: -->
<Property Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
  <RegistrySearch Key="SOFTWARE\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.AppName)" Root="HKLM" Type="raw" Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER_REGSEARCH" Name="Path" />
</Property>
```

```
  <Directory Id="BIN" Name="bin" />
  <Directory Id="HELP" Name="help" />
  <Directory Id="GENERATED" Name="generated" />

  <Component Id="RemoveAll" Guid="THE-GUID-HERE">
    <RemoveFile Id="RemoveAllFilesOnUninstall" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" />
    <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveAllFoldersOnUninstall" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" On="uninstall" />

    <!-- add this: -->
    <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.AppName)" Name="Path" Type="string" Value="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]" KeyPath="yes" />

    <util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />
  </Component>

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`RemoveFolderEx`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/removefolderex.html) in WixUtilExtension. I wrote about it [on my blog](https://www.joyofsetup.com/2011/01/21/tactical-directory-nukes/) back when I introduced it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have added  `RemoveFolderEx` to my declaration, but the folder GENERATED still remains.