# WIX util:RemoveFolderEx does not work

Tags: wix

I have wix installer with bootstraper for some application what creates additional files in application folder during his work and I have to remove these files during uninstall. According to https://www.hass.de/content/wix-how-use-removefolderex-your-xml-scripts and other same examples I have next parts of code:

1. Define property:

   ```
   <Property Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
     <RegistrySearch Key="SOFTWARE\ProductName" 
                     Root="HKLM" 
                     Type="raw" 
                     Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER_REGSEARCH" 
                     Name="Path" />
   </Property>
   ```
2. Define component:

   ```
   <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="ProductName">
     <Component Id="RemoveAll" Guid="some-guid">
       <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" 
                      Key="Software\ProductName" 
                      Type="string" 
                      Name="Path" 
                      Value="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]" 
                      KeyPath="yes"/>
       <util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" 
                            Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />
     </Component>
   </Directory>
   ```
3. Add component to feature:

   ```
   <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="ProductName" Level="1">
     ...
     <ComponentRef Id="RemoveAll" />
     ...
   </Feature>
   ```

Then when I try to uninstall this application I have next lines in wix logs:

```
...
MSI (s) (B4:64) [13:05:58:798]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding APPLICATIONFOLDER property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files(x86)\ProductName\'
...
Action start 13:05:58: WixRemoveFoldersEx.
MSI (s) (B4:48) [13:05:58:914]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding _APPLICATIONFOLDER_0 property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ProductName\'.
WixRemoveFoldersEx:  Recursing path: C:\Program Files (x86)\ProductName\ for row: wrfE932DA8DA501DD981493D5D9F4EFDD75.
MSI (s) (B4:64) [13:05:58:918]: Doing action: CostInitialize
MSI (s) (B4:64) [13:05:58:918]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 13:05:58: WixRemoveFoldersEx. Return value 1.
...
```

But nothing heppens and all additional files are present in the application folder, and accordingly the folder also is present. I have no idea why and I do not know what need to change to resolve this problem.

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Did you see [How To Delete Generated Folders/Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766359/how-can-i-delete-generated-folders-and-files-via-wix-on-uninstall)

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove any files created by the application before the folder can be removed. Try something like this:

```
<Component Id="RemoveOrphanFiles" Guid=InsertGUID KeyPath="yes">
   <RemoveFile Id="RemoveFiles" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" />
</Component>
```

and add a condition so that it only runs on uninstall ...
Hope this helps!

Comment: `util:RemoveFolderEx`'s purpose is to remove all files and folders in a folder without knowing all the names.