# Wix: How to remove an existing shortcut on Install?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, shortcut, custom-action

I need to remove an existing shortcut produced by other software on Install. Is this possible without using Custom Actions?

Comment: You might find something in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195919/removing-files-when-uninstalling-wix) that's helpful. Ultimately, it may indeed require a custom action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the RemoveFiles table. You will need to know where the shortcut, .lnk file lives to do this. The link that lurker provided should help get you going.

Comment: Correct. Although I would question "why".  Deleting a resource that you don't own is a component rule violation and won't prevent a repair of the other product from putting it back.  It also seems potentially unethical  although I don't know the exact scenario to make that judgement in this case.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. At last I did same as you mentioned. Although read your solution later, but marking it as the answer. :)

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: Well, in our situation we are replacing a shortcut of our own product already delivered to customers with a plugin tool. The scenario is that we have to deliver this plugin in a separate installer. In future, it would be part of our product.

Comment: I would look at the concept of micropackages and bootstrappers/chainers.  It should be possible to split your product line out into multiple installers and chain them together in different combinations to support the use cases you want.